# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths crashes with JSON imageUrls

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, tableview

i have a `UITableView`, which i fill with data from a JSON string.
take a look at the code in the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aNpU16KT).

at that point:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(
                    [indexPath],
                    withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            })
```

it fails.

I get the following message:

```
2016-11-06 16:32:06.579471 SO-33975355[4872:1389586] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 7 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'
```

if i remove the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, it works but i does not update the rows except for if you scroll or rotate the device. of course i want it to update directly.

I guess it has something to do with it being to fast? But i am completely clueless since i modified [this from the example](http://swiftarchitect.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/SO-33975355.zip).  (the example does not work with JSON but with urls from wikipedia)

i would be glad if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Before making the call for `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` make sure that your tableView is already created and you properly set the `dataSource`. Also below two datasource should get called for your tableView (before `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`).

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) {
        //Please return the maximum number of rows you are expecting from JSON. This is required because when you do reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, it should know that row index already exist
    }
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       //Return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:

> reason: 'attempt to delete row 7 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'

You are trying to reload the first row in section 7, but section 7 has zero rows, so there is no first row.

Tripple check your data model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 self.tableView.beginUpdates()
 self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(
                    [indexPath],
                    withRowAnimation: .Fade)
 self.tableView.endUpdates()
```